# Expected value and differentiation commute in a simple case

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, summation

In the text below (from Ross's book on probability), shouldn't it be 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum e^{tX}p(x)\right)=\sum \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{tX}\right)p(x)
$$
and similarly for the integral? *i.e.*, shouldn't the probability mass/density function unaffected by the differentiation operator?

[image]

Comment: The text is just emphasising that the order of the linear operations can be interchanged and not distracting the reader by distributing the stuff on which they are operating.  $~\frac{\mathrm d ~}{\mathrm d t}\sum_x (\operatorname{stuff}) = \sum_x \frac{\mathrm d ~}{\mathrm d t} (\operatorname{stuff})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, indeed
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sum_x e^{tX}p(x)\right]
= \sum_x \frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{tX}p(x)\right]
= \sum_x \frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{tX}\right]p(x)
$$
as you suggest since $p(x)$ is constant with respect to $t$. Ross does not need to simplify it for some reason.